# What model should i use to extract relation between words

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word

I want to create a ML model which would give a score from 0 to 1 which would signify the relation between them.

I know about Relationship Extraction(RE) but that's more related with sentences based relation. Instead i want to input two words and that should output the relation between them and a input dataset being a lot of sentences.

Comment: Please explain with an example. Do you want two output W1-->Dataset and W2-->Dataset?

Comment: How do you extract a relation between two words from a sentence?